# Bitcoin Core resume

Tags: synchronization

iam downloading the 350GB Core database via slow network.
iam not shure, if an correct resume occurs, if i need to breask the transmission.
my question:
is there any risk for inconsistence of bitcoin database, when i start multiple times?
has bitcoin core the ability to resume after stopping download?
That would be an great help to give a clear hint for that

thanks
lutz

Answer (score 1):

No, it should continue at the same speed once the connections are made after it is launched.

Force quitting Bitcoin would harm the database. You will be fine as long as you respect the "don't shut down your computer before this window disappears"